# Cordova app posting to FB and hash key issues

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

From my cordova app I am trying to post content to a users FB feed...from within my app the user logins successfully to FB (my app gets proper "connected" status with user/secret tokens etc)...but when I go to actually post something with the `facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog()` function I continually get a generic `sorry, something went wrong` FB error page...and when I close that page a `4201 - user cancelled dialog` is returned to my app.

I have been troubleshooting for 2 days and can't figure it out...so now I am looking at everything and wondering if my issue is related to the hash key.  Yet I am not getting any hash key errors that others have been reporting.

I am implementing FB into my cordova app.  I created the FB app profile, got my app ID and fed that as a variable when adding the cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin to my app.

On my pc, I then create the Android hash key with the keytool and exporting with keytool/OpenSSL and copying that hash key back into FB app profile.

But when I compile my cordova app, how/where is the app getting the hash key from?  I don't recall telling my app where my keystore is?  How does it know to go grab it?...does it even do this at all?

Can someone explain this to me? Or can someone point me in another direction as to why I am unable to post?

Comment: Can you please post the logs from logcat?

Comment: @dazza5000 - I think I found out the cordova/FB hash key conflict...adding the correct testing hash key from `\.android\debug.keystore` to my FB app profile now.  This def was not the key I previously defined.  Hoping this fixes it...report back in a few

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The docs are slim at best on this subject.

By default, ionic/cordova uses the %HOME%.android\debug.keystore hash key during development builds (ie: ionic build android). This is the DEVELOPMENT key you need to extract and add to the FB Android app profile. The default password for this debug.kestore (for both store and key) is android.

When you compile your app for publication, you create your own keystore (ie: \your\path\app.keystore) and reuse that key during the final android compile process (before submitting to store). You will need to add this hash key to the FB Android app profile too. This is the PRODUCTION key.

Both keys should be added to the FB Android app profile…if you ever have to change a key, then the FB app profile must be updated too. Probably best just to add another key versus deleting the old…if you delete the old one and users are on older versions of your app, then deleting the old key will prevent those users from interacting with FB.